# FIR Coefficient scaling

Tags: matlab, fpga

I am trying to scale the FIR coefficients generated by matlab. I have found the following example, but I am unable to figure out the scaling factor from the example

```
b = 0.0080 0.2176 0.5488 0.2176 0.0080 
>> [bsc, scfac]=fscale(b, bits) 
bsc = 479 12989 32767 12989 479 
scfac = 5.9702e+04
```

**b** represents the coefficients, **fscale** is some custom function used to scale the coefficients, it takes **b** and number of **bits** (16 in this case) and outputs the scaled coefficients **bsc** and the scale factor **scfac**, the FIR filter needs to be implemented on an FPGA. I am trying to figure out how the scale factor is calculated.

Comment: Did you try opening up `fscale` and seeing what the code does?

Comment: I do not have access to fscale, I just found some powerpoint slides while searching for scaling techniques. Also so far what I have understood about scaling is that the coefficients needs to be multiplied with 2^b (where b is the number of bits being used) in my case b = 16 bits which makes the scaling factor 65536, but here it is 59702.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a 16 bits representation of your integer coefficients. Apparently it is 16 bits signed. So, their range is:

```
[-2^15..2^15-1] = [-32768..32767]
```

As your largest initial coefficient, in absolute value, is `c ~= 0.5488` and it is positive, the scaling factor is such that:

```
c * scfac = 2^15-1 = 32767
scfac = 32767 / c ~= 32767 / 0.5488 ~= 5.9702e+04
```

Qed.

Note that because your real values are printed by Matlab with 4 digits only after the decimal point the `scfac` calculated by Matlab differs slightly from the one you can compute with `32767 / 0.5488` (`~ 59707`). If you ask Matlab to print more digits, you will quickly see that the real value is 59702.xxxxxx...

Note also that your question has very few to do with FPGAs.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I am trying to implement the filter on an FPGA, that is why I needed to scale the coefficients